# Xcode 5 llvm-g++ and llvm-gcc path?

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, compiler-construction, tesseract

I'm building an app for iOS7 with Xcode 5 using Google Tesseract OCR:
http://lois.di-qual.net/blog/install-and-use-tesseract-on-ios-with-tesseract-ios/

It worked fine with English recognition but I couldn't add any other language to the project. Then I found some other projects do it successfully by compiling Tesseract library:
http://inspirationteam.weebly.com/home/compile-use-tesseract-ocr-lib-301-on-ios
http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/

According to these articles, my llvm-g++ and llvm-gcc should be in

```
export CXX="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-g++"
export CC="$DEVROOT/usr/bin/llvm-gcc"
```

With $DEVROOT should be something like

```
export DEVROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
```

While I'm using Xcode 5 and Mac OSX 9.2 (I've heard that there're somethings had changed about C compiler with these guys), these paths didn't work for me:

```
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.3.0
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for gcc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/phuoc-de/Desktop/a/leptonica-1.71':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I've already installed Command line, but it still didn't work.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: That article is 2 years old and I don't see how changing the compiler will help with the issue you face (you don't say you are unable to compile tesseract, do you).

Comment: yeah I couldn't compile tesseract. I know it's an old article, and I have tried every solution but no luck so far. So I decided to compile the library again and got this problem. Do you know any other way?I would be really appreciate. Thank you for coming by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/blob/master/TesseractOCR/build_dependencies.sh)

```
export CXX=`xcrun -find c++`
export CC=`xcrun -find cc`
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

My days of using `configure`, `autoconf` and friends are at an end as I can pretty much find everything I want from [Macports](http://macports.org).

For me it's as simple as typing:

```
$ sudo port install tesseract
```

and going to make tea.